# Python: Find a word within a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to find a word within a string with Python.

```
str1 = 'This string'
if 'is' in str1:
    print str1
```

In the above example I would want it to not print str1. While in the following example I would want it to print str2.

```
str2 = 'This is a string'
if 'is' in str2:
    print str2
```

How would I go about doing this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the string into words and search them:

```
if 'is' in str1.split(): # 'is' in ['This', 'string']
    print(str1) # never printed

if 'is' in str2.split(): # 'is' in ['This', 'is', 'a', 'string']
    print(str2) # printed
```

Comment: Just a small point to take: if case insensitive, just turn the sentence into lower case fist.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Also I am using lower() before I compare the string.

Answer (score 5):

Use regex's word boundary also works

```
import re

if re.findall(r'\bis\b', str1):
    print str1
```